# How can I improve the speed of this list iteration in Python 3.9.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, loops

The following code is a measured hot spot, distilled from some code I'm writing.  I'm trying to figure out how to speed up this loop in Python 3.9.0.   I measure the same loop to be >30x faster using `std::vector` in VC++ 2019.

As you can see, I've tried a few different methods.  The `map()` function appears to return an iterator, so I converted it to a list to measure the full cost of execution.

I feel this is a fairly natural way to represent my data.  I could certainly work on some representational or algorithmic improvements here.  However, I'm sort of surprised that iteration is so slow in this case, and I'd like to see if it can be improved, first.

Performance results from executing: `python listIteration.py`

```
Iteration by index
66.66 ms
60.90 ms
62.74 ms
Total: 124998250000
Iteration by index -- just integers
55.22 ms
55.27 ms
80.84 ms
Total: 124998250000
Iteration by object
56.48 ms
60.30 ms
55.77 ms
Total: 124998250000
List comprehension
235.34 ms
328.15 ms
272.47 ms
Total: 124998250000
Map
310.81 ms
353.87 ms
300.27 ms
Total: 124998250000
```

Code:

```
import time

def makeList():
    data = []
    for i in range(500000):
        data.append([i, i, i])
    return data

def makeListOfInts():
    data = []
    for i in range(500000):
        data.append(i)
    return data    

def dumpTime(delta):
    print("{:.2f}".format(1000.0*delta) + " ms")


NUM_TRIALS = 3

print("Iteration by index");
data = makeList()
for t in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    x1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    for j in range(len(data)):
        data[j][0] -= 1

    x2 = time.perf_counter()
    dumpTime(x2-x1)
total = sum([x[0] for x in data])
print("Total: "+ str(total))

print("Iteration by index -- just integers");
data = makeListOfInts()
for t in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    x1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    for j in range(len(data)):
        data[j] -= 1

    x2 = time.perf_counter()
    dumpTime(x2-x1)
total = sum(data)
print("Total: "+ str(total))

print("Iteration by object");
data = makeList()
for t in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    x1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    for v in data:
        v[0] -= 1

    x2 = time.perf_counter()
    dumpTime(x2-x1)
total = sum([x[0] for x in data])    
print("Total: "+ str(total))

print("List comprehension");
data = makeList()
for t in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    x1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    data = [[x[0]-1, x[1], x[2]] for x in data]
    
    x2 = time.perf_counter()
    dumpTime(x2-x1)
total = sum([x[0] for x in data])
print("Total: "+ str(total))    

print("Map");
data = makeList()
for t in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    x1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    # here we convert the map object to a list, because apparently
    # map() returns an iterator, and we want to measure the full cost
    # of the computation
    data = list(map(lambda x: [x[0]-1, x[1], x[2]], data))
    
    x2 = time.perf_counter()
    dumpTime(x2-x1)
total = sum([x[0] for x in data])
print("Total: "+ str(total))
```

Comment: Python code is going to be slower than C++. No way around it, unless you eliminate / outsource the iteration to a C-backend, which is what `numpy` does.

Comment: `for j in range(len(data)):` => `for j in data:` then no need to index into data using j in the following statement, just use `j[0]-=1`.

Comment: barny, yes, that is the "iteration by object" experiment, is that what you mean?

Comment: It’s the first two, actually, although I was referring to the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Python code is going to be slower than C++. No way around it, unless you eliminate / outsource the iteration to a C-backend, which is what `numpy` does.

For example, you could do

```
import numpy as np

def makeArray():
    data = np.vstack((np.arange(500000), np.arange(500000), np.arange(500000))).T
    return data

def makeArrayOfInts():
    data = np.arange(500000)
    return data
```

And then, you wouldn't need to iterate at all.

```
data = makeArray()
for t in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    x1 = time.perf_counter()
    data[:, 0] = data[:, 0] - 1
    x2 = time.perf_counter()
    dumpTime(x2-x1)
total = sum(data[:, 0])
print("Total: "+ str(total))

data = makeArrayOfInts()
for t in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    x1 = time.perf_counter()
    data = data - 1
    x2 = time.perf_counter()
    dumpTime(x2-x1)
total = sum(data)
print("Total: "+ str(total))
```

Both these are *superfast*: the trials each take ~1ms, as opposed to ~50ms that is needed for iterating over the lists.

Comment: I used numpy with only slight modifications to your code (set dtype='int64'), and I get an average of <1ms for the summation.  Looks like that's the way to go for this data structure, if I want to stay in Python.  Thanks.